# AWS RDS PostgresSQL 14.7 sum(pg_column_size(t.*)) is way greater than pg_relation_size(t)

Tags: postgresql

I am on a mission to optimize our DB and aiming to move out some text columns out from one of our high traffic tables.
I tried to understand which columns are stored in the TOAST table as chunks.
For the record I had my faith in the search, read the official reference and many se topics. Many referred to pg_.._size functions and many outlined that pg_column_size does NOT include the column data stored in the TOAST tables.

But I am very confused after ending up with the query result below, am I missing something here?

```
-- the query
select
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(oid)) _total_table
, (select pg_size_pretty(sum (pg_column_size(t.*))) from test t) as _sum_column_size
, pg_indexes_size(oid) _ix_size
, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)) _toast
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid)) _rel_table
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid, 'main')) _main_table
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm')) _fsm_table
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm')) _vm_table
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid, 'init')) _init_table
,* from pg_catalog.pg_class
where relname = 'test'
```

```
-- Result of the query
Name               |Value     |
-------------------+----------+
_total_table       |26 MB     |
_sum_column_size   |22 MB     | pg_column_size total, which seems to include the toast data ?!?
_ix_size           |0         |
_toast             |19 MB     | data stored on the toast table ?
_rel_table         |6648 kB   | data stored on table's page files, right?
_main_table        |6648 kB   |
_fsm_table         |24 kB     |
_vm_table          |8192 bytes|
_init_table        |0 bytes   |
```

Answer (score 0):

`pg_column_size()` shows the detoasted size:

```
CREATE TABLE toastme(t text);

ALTER TABLE toastme ALTER t SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;

INSERT INTO toastme VALUES (REPEAT('0123456789', 1000));

SELECT pg_column_size(t) FROM toastme;

 pg_column_size 
════════════════
          10000
(1 row)

SELECT pg_relation_size('toastme');

 pg_relation_size 
══════════════════
             8192
(1 row)
```

That explains what you see, right? Don't trust blog posts without verifying the statements yourself.

As to the question how you can tell if a certain column is toasted or not: you cannot do that easily. The only way I know is using the `paginspect` extension: you can extract a block of data with the `get_raw_page()` function, and you can use `heap_page_item_attrs()` to inspect the raw data on that page. There you will see a TOAST pointer (if you know how to read the data). To find the block that contains a row, look at the first number of the row's `ctid`. Sorry, but there is no easier way.

Comment: Thanks for this Laurenz, my confusion was originated from all other posts/comments which said 'pg_column_size does not count toast size'. now it makes sense. But why a wide variety of comments/posts say that pg_column_size does not include toast data though. And can you show me any reference documentation indicating that? Or is this solely based on testing/seeing yourself?

Comment: my original questions stands. 'I am trying to understand which columns are stored in the toast table?'. Your answer explains that I can not accomplish this by using pg_column_size, then how? Thanks again.